# Were my DNS servers changed?

Tags: google-chrome, dns, internet, malware

I recently stupidly clicked on a suspicious link and since then, Chrome stalls for a few seconds before reaching a web page.

I suspect my DNS servers may have been changed (among other possible suspicions).

How can I check what my DNS servers were vs. what they are now? Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your pc is dhcp (doesn't have a static ip), then login into your router to see what the default DNS settings are. Those are the default "before" value for your pc.
Then to find the current pc dns settins, go into a cmd window and type:

> ipconfig /all

(for windows), or in Linux (google chrome os):

> cat /etc/resolv.conf

Another possibility to check is if the malware installed a browser extension that runs before the page loads. Check Chrome's extensions from its settings menu and disable everything as a test.

Comment: I disabled all the extensions and it works normally now... so something is up

Comment: And for OS X (Mac's), it's `scutil --dns`